# Are there good tutorials on how to use PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Maybe someone did a tutorial that shows the important thing: Setting everything up and using it with MySQL?

Comment: I found this one : [PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: [(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) which I wrote based on the thousands questions I answered here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

MySQL.com: [Using MySQL with PDO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/index.html)
PHP.net: [PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 25):

I think the article *[Why you Should be using PHP's PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)* is great. It is simple, clear, and organized.

Comment: +1 I agree - BUT, look at the comments, most of the code is syntatially inorrect, as he ommits the `prepare`. Once you get past that, it is a great guide. In fact, it is how I learned.

Comment: They tell you to run an extra query(!) only to count the rows already returned by a query, which is a nonsense. They also tell you to "always wrap your PDO operations in a try/catch" which is a nonsense again. And they fail to explain the real PDO benefits. In essence, PDO learned from tutsplus is toilsome and error prone.

Answer (score 6):

PHP.net has the best stuff.  I would check out [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) for an example.

Answer (score 5):

Something I came across with PDO and [BLOBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) is that you can use that for encrypted data in MySQL. A good example of using BLOBs with encryption (so information in the database itself is encrypted) can be seen in:

*[Project mySQL PDO: Step by step guide to working with a mySQL database with the PDO to help eliminate SQL injection along with using encryption](http://www.virtualsecrets.com/pdo-encryption-mysql-from-php.html)*.