# Connect to DB including "mysql_select" convert to pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my connect page to sql server

```
<?php
$user="test";
$parola="test1";
$bazadate="test";  //Numele bazei de date sql//
$host="localhost"; //In general se foloseste localhost//
mysql_connect($host,$user,$parola);
@mysql_select_db($bazadate) or die( "Nu ma pot conecta la baza ta de date! <br/ > 
Sigur ai completat userul, parola si numele bazei de date?");
?>
```

I've tried the down code, but i receive "No database selected":

```
<?php
/* SQL connect PDO */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost';
$user = 'test';
$password = 'test1';

try {
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Conectare SQL nereusita: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

PDO class kills me completley...

Comment: Any error message shown?

Comment: yes i am receive no database selected when use second connect code (PDO) but first code works good

Comment: What is your database name ? Are you sure it is `test` ?

Comment: +1 for trying to make the conversion to PDO.

Comment: Yes Sahal test is my database name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost';
```

the parameters are in the wrong order

The order in [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) is

```
$dbn = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$bazadatet', $user, $parola);
```

Where

```
$user="test";
$parola="test1";    //table
$bazadate="test";  //Numele bazei de date sql//
$host="localhost"; //In general se foloseste localhost//
```

Change the order to `host & dbname`

Comment: Thx David, i've plused you and for other users in my situation the correct code is: `<?php

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'test';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'test1';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=test", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    //echo 'Conectat la baza de date';//
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>`

Answer (score -2):

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Taken from: [Are there good tutorials on how to use PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943069/are-there-good-tutorials-on-how-to-use-pdo)

Comment: Please post solutions here and not just links to them.