# PHP OOP retrieve data from database, initializing it and echo-ing it

Tags: php, oop, initialization, echo, data-retrieval

Hi all I need your advice on whether the following way of coding is acceptable and what better way to code in terms of 3 things, retrieving data, initializing variables and echoing it.

```
class Product {

private $product_name = array();
private $num_rows;

public function __construct() {
    include 'connect.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM product where product_status= 'open' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $this->num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $this->product_name[] = $record['product_name'];
    }
}

public function get_rows() {
    return $this->num_rows;
}

public function get_name($count) {
    return $this->product_name[$count];
}
```

}

```
$product = new Product();
$rows = $product->get_rows();

for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {

    echo $product->get_name($i);
}
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are really not acceptable anymore, thats first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like your class naming much.  You call it a Product but it is in fact a ProductCollection or similar.  In fact it is tied to a particular kind of ProductCollection an OpenProductCollection or OpenProducts if you prefer.

What if you wanted ClosedProducts or some other status as may have been set in product_status in your db?

```
$pc = new ProductsCollection('open');
```

Your use of 'SELECT * FROM product ...' when you only want `name` also seems wasteful, or would if each product had 100 fields .... we don't know how many fields you have.

So you might want to do the equivalent of:

```
$pc = new ProductsCollection;
$pc->set_fields(array('id', 'name'));
$pc->get_status_open();  // return your array
```

You could look at using magic __get and __set as another way to get round this, otherwise you could tightly tie your class to your table with get_name, get_price, get_manufacturer and so on.

Regarding the remarks about mysql_* functions if you move to either mysqli or PDO you can also SELECT into an OBJECT, so your result set could be an array of pre-filled Product objects. (ie a Product class you write which represents a single product).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you have to worry about is the database handling. Try PDO rather than mysql_* functions. Follow this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943069/are-there-good-tutorials-on-how-to-use-pdo). That's all. Other than that everything else seems fine to me.

One last thing every-time you create `$product = new Product();` database query will run. My question is it mandatory ? can you put it in a separate function. So that when you need it you can call it and get the data.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is load 10 latest product on my index.php page by maybe adding a LIMIT 10 on SQL SELECT. I am not so sure which is better, a seperate function or on the contructor. Anyway thanks I'll look into this.