# SQL error when updating

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL error below when I run my PHP SQL code:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE useid = 8' at line 1

```
mysql_query("UPDATE free_ebook SET math = $assign_math WHERE useid = $newuserid;")or die(mysql_error());
```

The `math` field is `int(10)`, and `useid` is also `int(10)`.

Comment: Hello Mr. Smith, welcome to SO.

Comment: what do your variables resolve to? maybe they're unescaped strings that are terminating your query

Comment: Provide the value of `$assign_math`

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: @Sean $assign_math = $_POST['input_math'];

Which is an integer

Comment: Typically when the error message is `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '...` then the issue the value/syntax before. Try wrapping it with single quotes  - `... SET math = '$assign_math' ... `

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the field name should probably be `userid`, not `useid`.

Alternatively, try enclosing the values in single quotes, like this:

```
"UPDATE free_ebook SET math = '".$assign_math."' WHERE useid = '".$newuserid."';"
```

or even

```
"UPDATE free_ebook SET math = '{$assign_math}' WHERE useid = '{$newuserid}';"
```

---

On the topic: `mysql_query()` is deprecated, you should be using the PDO extension. It's easy (maybe easier!) to learn and a lot more secure:

[Are there good tutorials on how to use PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943069/are-there-good-tutorials-on-how-to-use-pdo)

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

<s>http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/</s>

<s>http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html</s>

Comment: Don't send people to nettuts or phpro pages for tutorials. Both of those sites tell people to use PDO with emulated prepares, which negates any advantages gained from prepared statements. Instead direct people to this page: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers