# php data from database is not shown after search

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, search-engine

I am new to php and trying to make a search function on name and date but I have a problem.

My problem is that the search function sees all the effected rows from the search but does not show them. I load all the data from the database as default on my page and I want that if the `$_GET['go']` from search isset that all the default data isn't shown anymore and only the results from the search are shown. Now he always shows that default data. Except from the `$_GET['by']` there is no data shown.

I also try to use PDO but I don't know much about that.... so there's a possibility I am doing something wrong with that too.

My PHP code:

```
<?php


            ini_set('display_errors',1);
            ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
            error_reporting(-1);

            //connect  to the database
            $db_host = "localhost";
            $db_username = "**";
            $db_password = "**";
            $db_name = "**";

            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' .$db_host . ';dbname='. $db_name . '',$db_username,$db_password);


            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                if(isset($_GET['go'])){
                    if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['search'])){
                        $zoek=$_POST['search'];

                        var_dump($zoek); //this will display on the screen the content of the variable 

                        // query  the database table
                        $sql="SELECT v.vacatureID, v.werkgeverID, v.functie, v.omschrijvingKort, v.datum, w.werkgeverID, w.naamBedrijf, w.plaats, w.image FROM vacature AS v JOIN werkgever AS w ON v.werkgeverID = w.werkgeverID WHERE w.naamBedrijf LIKE  '%" . $zoek .  "%' ORDER BY datum DESC";
                        // run  the query against the mysql query function
                        $result = $db->prepare($sql); 
                        $result->execute(); 

                        // count number of rows that are effected
                        $rows = $result->fetchAll();
                        $numrows = count($rows);
                        echo  "<p>" .$numrows . " results found for '" . $zoek . "'</p>"; 

                        // create  while loop and loop through result set
                        while($row = $result->fetch()){
                                $Functie=$row['functie'];
                                $OmschrijvingKort=$row['omschrijvingKort'];
                                $Datum=$row['datum'];
                                $Bedrijf=$row['naamBedrijf'];
                                $Plaats=$row['plaats'];
                                $Image=$row['image'];
                                $ID=$row['vacatureID'];

                            // truncate
                            if (strlen($Functie) > 20) {
                                // truncate string
                                $stringCut = substr($Functie, 0, 20);
                                // make sure it ends in a word
                                $Functie = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'...'; 
                            }
                            if (strlen($Bedrijf) > 25) {
                                // truncate string
                                $stringCut2 = substr($Bedrijf, 0, 14);
                                // make sure it ends in a word
                                $Bedrijf = substr($stringCut2, 0, strrpos($stringCut2, ' ')).'...'; 
                            }
                            if (strlen($OmschrijvingKort) > 63) {
                                // truncate string
                                $stringCut2 = substr($OmschrijvingKort, 0, 63);
                                // make sure it ends in a word
                                $OmschrijvingKort = substr($stringCut2, 0, strrpos($stringCut2, ' ')).'...'; 
                            }
                            // display the result of the array
                            echo 
                            "
                                <div class='vacatureinfo2'>
                                    <img class='userimg2' src='../../uploads/userimage/". $Image ."' id='imge'/>
                                    <p class='func-br-pl pull-left'>". $Functie ." - ". $Bedrijf ." - ". $Plaats ."</p><p class='dtm pull-right'>". $Datum ."</p>
                                    <div class='omschrijvingkort2'>
                                        ". $OmschrijvingKort ."
                                    </div>
                                    <a href='#' class='pull-right'>Meer informatie</a>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                            ";
                        }
                    }
                    elseif(preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/", $_POST['searchdate'])){
                        $zoek=$_POST['searchdate'];

                        var_dump($zoek); //this will display on the screen the content of the variable 

                        //-query  the database table
                        $sql="SELECT v.vacatureID, v.werkgeverID, v.functie, v.omschrijvingKort, v.datum, w.werkgeverID, w.naamBedrijf, w.plaats, w.image FROM vacature AS v JOIN werkgever AS w ON v.werkgeverID = w.werkgeverID WHERE v.datum LIKE '%" . $zoek ."%' ORDER BY datum DESC";
                        //-run  the query against the mysql query function
                        $result = $db->prepare($sql); 
                        $result->execute(); 
                        $rows = $result->fetchAll();
                        $numrows = count($rows);
                        echo  "<p>" .$numrows . " results found for '" . $zoek . "'</p>"; 

                        //-create  while loop and loop through result set
                        while($row = $result->fetch()){
                                $Functie=$row['functie'];
                                $OmschrijvingKort=$row['omschrijvingKort'];
                                $Datum=$row['datum'];
                                $Bedrijf=$row['naamBedrijf'];
                                $Plaats=$row['plaats'];
                                $Image=$row['image'];
                                $ID=$row['vacatureID'];

                            //-truncate
                            if (strlen($Functie) > 20) {
                                // truncate string
                                $stringCut = substr($Functie, 0, 20);
                                // make sure it ends in a word
                                $Functie = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'...'; 
                            }
                            if (strlen($Bedrijf) > 25) {
                                // truncate string
                                $stringCut2 = substr($Bedrijf, 0, 14);
                                // make sure it ends in a word
                                $Bedrijf = substr($stringCut2, 0, strrpos($stringCut2, ' ')).'...'; 
                            }
                            if (strlen($OmschrijvingKort) > 63) {
                                // truncate string
                                $stringCut2 = substr($OmschrijvingKort, 0, 63);
                                // make sure it ends in a word
                                $OmschrijvingKort = substr($stringCut2, 0, strrpos($stringCut2, ' ')).'...'; 
                            }
                            //-display the result of the array
                            echo 
                            "
                                <div class='vacatureinfo2'>
                                    <img class='userimg2' src='../../uploads/userimage/". $Image ."' id='imge'/>
                                    <p class='func-br-pl pull-left'>". $Functie ." - ". $Bedrijf ." - ". $Plaats ."</p><p class='dtm pull-right'>". $Datum ."</p>
                                    <div class='omschrijvingkort2'>
                                        ". $OmschrijvingKort ."
                                    </div>
                                    <a href='#' class='pull-right'>Meer informatie</a>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                            ";
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>";
                    }
                }
            }//end of search form script                
            if(isset($_GET['by'])){
                $letter=$_GET['by'];

                $sql="SELECT v.vacatureID, v.werkgeverID, v.functie, v.omschrijvingKort, v.datum, w.werkgeverID, w.naamBedrijf, w.plaats, w.image FROM vacature AS v JOIN werkgever AS w ON v.werkgeverID = w.werkgeverID WHERE SUBSTRING(w.naamBedrijf,1,1) LIKE  '%" . $letter .  "%' ORDER BY datum DESC";

                $result = $db->prepare($sql); 
                $result->execute(); 

                $rows = $result->fetchAll();
                $numrows = count($rows);
                echo  "<p>" .$numrows . " results found for '" . $letter . "'</p>"; 

                //-create  while loop and loop through result set
                while($row = $result->fetch()){
                    $Functie=$row['functie'];
                    $OmschrijvingKort=$row['omschrijvingKort'];
                    $Datum=$row['datum'];
                    $Bedrijf=$row['naamBedrijf'];
                    $Plaats=$row['plaats'];
                    $Image=$row['image'];
                    $ID=$row['vacatureID'];

                    //-truncate
                    if (strlen($Functie) > 20) {
                        // truncate string
                        $stringCut = substr($Functie, 0, 20);
                        // make sure it ends in a word
                        $Functie = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'...'; 
                    }
                    if (strlen($Bedrijf) > 25) {
                        // truncate string
                        $stringCut2 = substr($Bedrijf, 0, 14);
                        // make sure it ends in a word
                        $Bedrijf = substr($stringCut2, 0, strrpos($stringCut2, ' ')).'...'; 
                    }
                    if (strlen($OmschrijvingKort) > 63) {
                        // truncate string
                        $stringCut2 = substr($OmschrijvingKort, 0, 63);
                        // make sure it ends in a word
                        $OmschrijvingKort = substr($stringCut2, 0, strrpos($stringCut2, ' ')).'...'; 
                    }

                    //-display  the result of the array
                    echo 
                    "
                        <div class='vacatureinfo2'>
                            <img class='userimg2' src='../../uploads/userimage/". $Image ."' id='imge'/>
                            <p class='func-br-pl pull-left'>". $Functie ." - ". $Bedrijf ." - ". $Plaats ."</p><p class='dtm pull-right'>". $Datum ."</p>
                            <div class='omschrijvingkort2'>
                                ". $OmschrijvingKort ."
                            </div>
                            <a href='#' class='pull-right'>Meer informatie</a>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    ";
                }
            }//end of our letter search script
            else{
                include('php/vacatureoverzichtphp.php');
            }
        ?>
```

In the `include('php/vacatureoverzichtphp.php');` I have the code for the default data that is shown on the page.

HTML code:

```
<form class="form-inline pull-right" method="post" action="vacatureoverzicht.php?go"  id="searchform">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Zoeken op: </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="zoekenBedrijf">Bedrijfsnaam of Datum</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="zoekenBedrijf" placeholder="Bedrijfsnaam">
                <label> of </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchdate" id="zoekenDatum" placeholder="Datum">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default">zoeken</button>
        </form>
        <br><br><br>
        <p><a  href="vacatureoverzicht.php">Alles</a> | <a  href="?by=A">A</a> | <a  href="?by=B">B</a> | <a  href="?by=C">C</a> | <a  href="?by=D">D</a> | <a  href="?by=E">E</a> | <a  href="?by=F">F</a>
        | <a  href="?by=G">G</a> | <a  href="?by=H">H</a> | <a  href="?by=I">I</a> | <a  href="?by=J">J</a> | <a  href="?by=K">K</a> | <a  href="?by=L">L</a> 
        | <a  href="?by=M">M</a> | <a  href="?by=N">N</a> | <a  href="?by=O">O</a> | <a  href="?by=P">P</a> | <a  href="?by=Q">Q</a> | <a  href="?by=R">R</a>
        | <a  href="?by=S">S</a> | <a  href="?by=T">T</a> | <a  href="?by=U">U</a> | <a  href="?by=V">V</a> | <a  href="?by=W">W</a> | <a  href="?by=X">X</a> 
        | <a  href="?by=Y">Y</a> | <a  href="?by=Z">Z</a></p>
```

Comment: do you see your very first `var_dump($zoek);` output?

Comment: @Alex Yes it says `string(2) "wo"` and from my count I also get the right number of rows back `6 results found for 'wo'` and if I try the query in my database if gives all the right results back.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @MarcB can you please tell me what I have to do to make my code safe for sql inection attacks? Because as mentioned earlier I am new to php and PDO  and this is the only way I thought my code would be safe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I got your code correctly the issue is here:

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll();
$numrows = count($rows);
echo  "<p>" .$numrows . " results found for '" . $zoek . "'</p>"; 

// create  while loop and loop through result set
while($row = $result->fetch()){
```

So you did `fetchAll()` first and then you are trying to `while($row = $result->fetch()){`. but you can't fetch again from the same result.

so you should change your loop header to :

```
 foreach($rows as $row){
```

So the full fragment will be like:

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll();
$numrows = count($rows);
echo  "<p>" .$numrows . " results found for '" . $zoek . "'</p>"; 

// create  while loop and loop through result set
foreach ($rows as $row ){
```

hope that will help :-)

Comment: alternatively, `$numrows = $result->num_rows; while($row = $result->fetch())`,

Comment: @Alex thanks that helped! But the default data from the include is still shown after the results of the search. Do you know how I can fix that too? Because if I run the $_GET['by'] code the include is not shown...

Comment: Never mind... My code is working fine now!! :-D I just had to change the `else{include('php/vacatureoverzichtphp.php');}` to `if(!isset($_GET['go']) && !isset($_GET['by'])){ include('php/vacatureoverzichtphp.php');  }`