# PHP/SQL Query Returns Nothing

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to query a list of classes, teachers, extracurricular, and a student's major but when I run the query I get no results.

```
//query to get the student ID if user enters "name" on the page

 $student_name= $_POST["name"];
 $studentid= "SELECT studentid FROM students WHERE name='$student_name'";
 $id_query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $studentid);
 $student_id= mysqli_fetch_array($id_query);

//should query stuff related to the student.

 $sqlstudentquery= "SELECT c.name, c.teacher, e.name, m.name
   FROM students AS s
   LEFT JOIN classes AS c ON s.studentid = c.stude_id 
   LEFT JOIN extracurricular AS e ON s.studentid = e.stude_id 
   LEFT JOIN majors AS m ON s.studentid = m.stude_id 
 WHERE s.studentid='$student_id[0]'";
 $student_data = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlstudentquery);
```

When I enter a search term, the page will attempt to load but doesn't return any data.  I tried to enter the query manually on the database but it returns an empty query.  Should I be using an inner join rather than left?

edit: I did find a syntax error in my php after posting this.  I have fixed it.  SQL query still isn't working.

edit2: sql query works now thanks.

Comment: `print_r( $student_id);` chk this

Comment: In the first query you refer to the ID of a student as `SELECT student FROM` and on the second query you are using `s.studentid` which is `students AS s` so what is the correct field? Either your first or your second query is wrong.

Comment: If the query doesn't work in the DB interface this isn't a PHP question, it is a SQL/mysql question. What does the DB look like, can you provide a sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
>  $student_name= $_POST["name"];
>  $studentid= "SELECT student FROM students WHERE name='$name'";
>  $id_query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $studentid);
> ```

You are looking for name `$name` but you are only setting a varaible called `$student_name`

So in effect you are looking for values in the `Students` table that have `name=''`.

Also

> ```
>  WHERE s.studentid='$student_id[0]'";
> ```

You are looking for a `studentid` column value but this is checked against the data from the `student` column in the `student` table. This looks like your trying to check a numerical index field (`studentid`) with a varchar-type character value (`student`).

---

**Further details:**

You have the line `WHERE s.studentid='$student_id[0]'";` which in full taking the values from your current SQL queries is:

`student` table column named `student_id` is **s.student_id** and you are checking this against value `$sudent_id[0]` which is from the query above it the value of the `student` column in the `student` table. This means you will never find any results as it's comparing two columns that almost certainly contain different values.

---

You are wide open to SQL injection on this code and it is very highly advised to [use PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943069/are-there-good-tutorials-on-how-to-use-pdo) or otherwise fully and completely escape strings from user input and [use prepared statments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Might want to add a note about SQL injection possibility as well.

Comment: Silly, I realized the syntax error after I posted this.  Thanks.

Comment: @shelum I'm pleased it now works, but the code still looks like it wouldn't work as your comparing values from the column `student` and `studentid` , can you explain this? Cheers

Comment: `students` is the table, `studentid` is the student id. I had a typo that I edited.  That is what I fixed to get the query working.

Comment: Ok. It's a good idea when you discover the typo or fix to your problem to **NOT** just update your original question, as that in turn makes it unclear what you're asking and unclear what my answer is explaining, the best method is to *edit* your question and add a note at the bottom as to how you solved your issue, Cheers :-) @shelum